# How To pass php variable into ajax data

Tags: php, ajax

How can I send PHP  variable sprod into ajax i need to send this id to check.php page

```
<script>
function getState(val) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: {id: val, id2:$prod },
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("#style_code").children().remove();
        $("#style_image").children().remove();

         data.option.forEach(function (item) {
                $("#style_code").append('<option value="' + item.color_name + '">' + item.size + '</option>');
                $('#style_image').append('<img  src="images/'+item.image_name+'" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt="" />')               
            //$("#style_image").html(data);
            });
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: just modify like this `data: {id: val, id2:<?=$prod?> },`

Comment: Where does `$prod` come from first? I'm sure there's a better way to do this

Comment: it is in the same page where ajax is  . single.php and it is coming from query . on product table .

Comment: I would love to see the output of that query @basiclearner

Comment: Check my edited post. You have to add `'` around the key in your data store

Comment: <script>

function getState(val) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var prod='<?php echo $productid ?>';
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "check.php",
 data: {'id': val, 'id2':prod},
 dataType:'json',
  But it is  still giving error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
single.php?id=1:305 Uncaught ReferenceError: getState is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (single.php?id=1:305)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 var prod = <?php echo $prod ?>;
</script>
```

**Note**

This should only works if your page is in `.php` extension

Comment: my page is in .php extension but it is still not working .

Comment: whats the output of console.log(prod) and check the script in browser

Comment: I fetched the data from php and stored it in $prod like $prod=$row[''productid'];  then if i pass it in ajax it says " unexpected token >"  i am using this data: {id: val, pid:<?php echo $productid?> },

Comment: unexpected token in which line?? try `var prod = '<?php echo $prod ?>';` this and let me know the result

Comment: uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
 single.php?id=1:302 Uncaught ReferenceError: getState is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Answer (score 0):

use `<?php echo $prod ?>` to access php variables in ajax.

```
 data: {id: val, id2:<?php echo $prod ?> },
```

Comment: How about adding some explanation which is always good. It might be understandable to some, but newbies might not have a clue what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php ?>` tags in your script because you run it into ur .php file.

But you need to to open the `<?php ?>` tags to use php in the script tags.

Change

```
data: {id: val, id2:$prod },
```

To

```
data: {'id':val, 'id2':<?php echo $prod ?> },
```

Also(Better by my oppinion)

```
data: {'id': val, 'id2':<?= $prod ?> },
```

U can use `<?=?>` instead of `<?php ?>` to print something, so you don't need to write `echo` again.